# Invalid argument(s): No host specified in URI file:///p1

Tags: flutter, dart, uri

Pulling images from the network into a GridView.Builder()
The images are not displayed. [View screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wJhn.png)

```
    Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Shoppy'),
      ),
      body: GridView.builder(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          itemCount: loadedProducts.length,
          gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
            crossAxisCount: 2,
            childAspectRatio: 3 / 2,
            crossAxisSpacing: 8.0,
            mainAxisSpacing: 8.0,
          ),
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return ProductItem(
              loadedProducts[index].id,
              loadedProducts[index].imageUrl,
              loadedProducts[index].name,
            );
          }),
    );
```

```
I/flutter (11127): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY IMAGE RESOURCE SERVICE ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (11127): The following ArgumentError was thrown resolving an image codec:
I/flutter (11127): Invalid argument(s): No host specified in URI file:///p1
I/flutter (11127): 
I/flutter (11127): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
I/flutter (11127): #0      _HttpClient._openUrl (dart:_http/http_impl.dart:2313:9)
I/flutter (11127): #1      _HttpClient.getUrl (dart:_http/http_impl.dart:2208:48)
I/flutter (11127): #2      NetworkImage._loadAsync (package:flutter/src/painting/_network_image_io.dart:89:59)
I/flutter (11127): #3      NetworkImage.load (package:flutter/src/painting/_network_image_io.dart:51:14)
I/flutter (11127): #4      ImageProvider.resolveStreamForKey.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:503:13)
I/flutter (11127): #5      ImageCache.putIfAbsent (package:flutter/src/painting/image_cache.dart:360:22)
I/flutter (11127): #6      ImageProvider.resolveStreamForKey (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:501:80)
I/flutter (11127): #7      ScrollAwareImageProvider.resolveStreamForKey (package:flutter/src/widgets/scroll_aware_image_provider.dart:108:19)
I/flutter (11127): #8      ImageProvider.resolve.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:332:9)
I/flutter (11127): #9      ImageProvider._createErrorHandlerAndKey.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:462:26)
I/flutter (11127): #10     SynchronousFuture.then (package:flutter/src/foundation/synchronous_future.dart:43:29)
I/flutter (11127): #11     ImageProvider._createErrorHandlerAndKey.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:459:11)
I/flutter (11127): #15     ImageProvider._createErrorHandlerAndKey (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:451:16)
I/flutter (11127): #16     ImageProvider.resolve (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:329:5)
I/flutter (11127): #17     _ImageState._resolveImage (package:flutter/src/widgets/image.dart:1116:16)
I/flutter (11127): #18     _ImageState.didChangeDependencies (package:flutter/src/widgets/image.dart:1069:5)
I/flutter (11127): #19     StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4705:12)
I/flutter (11127): #20     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4520:5)
I/flutter (11127): ...     Normal element mounting (7 frames)
I/flutter (11127): #27     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3490:14)
I/flutter (11127): #28     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5991:32)
I/flutter (11127): ...     Normal element mounting (48 frames)
I/flutter (11127): #76     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3490:14)
I/flutter (11127): #77     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3258:18)
I/flutter (11127): #78     SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:1164:36)
I/flutter (11127): #79     SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement.createChild.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:1149:20)
I/flutter (11127): #80     BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2620:19)
I/flutter (11127): #81     SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement.createChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:1142:11)
I/flutter (11127): #82     RenderSliverMultiBoxAdaptor._createOrObtainChild.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart:356:23)
I/flutter (11127): #83     RenderObject.invokeLayoutCallback.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1868:58)
I/flutter (11127): #84     PipelineOwner._enableMutationsToDirtySubtrees (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:920:15)
I/flutter (11127): #85     RenderObject.invokeLayoutCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1868:13)
I/flutter (11127): #86     RenderSliverMultiBoxAdaptor._createOrObtainChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart:345:5)
I/flutter (11127): #87     RenderSliverMultiBoxAdaptor.addInitialChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart:429:5)
I/flutter (11127): #88     RenderSliverGrid.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_grid.dart:549:12)
I/flutter (11127): #89     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1769:7)
I/flutter (11127): #90     RenderSliverEdgeInsetsPadding.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_padding.dart:137:11)
I/flutter (11127): #91     RenderSliverPadding.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_padding.dart:377:11)
I/flutter (11127): #92     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1769:7)
I/flutter (11127): #93     RenderViewportBase.layoutChildSequence (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:454:13)
I/flutter (11127): #94     RenderViewport._attemptLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:1445:12)
I/flutter (11127): #95     RenderViewport.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:1354:20)
I/flutter (11127): #96     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1769:7)
I/flutter (11127): #97     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:115:13)
I/flutter (11127): #98     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1769:7)
I/flutter (11127): #99     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:115:13)
I/flutter (11127): #100    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1769:7)
I/flutter (11127): #101    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:115:13)
I/flutter (11127): #102    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1769:7)
I/flutter (11127): #103    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:115:13)
I/flutter (11127): #104    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1769:7)
I/flutter (11127): #105    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:115:13)
I/flutter (11127): #106    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1769:7)
I/flutter (11127): #107    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:115:13)
I/flutter (11127): #108    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1769:7)
I/flutter (11127): #109    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:115:13)
I/flutter (11127): #110    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1769:7)
I/flutter (11127): #111    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:115:13)
I/flutter (11127): #112    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1769:7)
I/flutter (11127): #113    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:115:13)
I/flutter (11127): #114    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1769:7)
I/flutter (11127): #115    MultiChildLayoutDelegate.layoutChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:173:11)
I/flutter (11127): #116    _ScaffoldLayout.performLayout (package:flutter/src/material/scaffold.dart:482:7)
I/flutter (11127): #117    MultiChildLayoutDelegate._callPerformLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:242:7)
I/flutter (11127): #118    RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:401:14)
I/flutter (11127): #119    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1769:7)
I/flutter (11127): #120    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:115:13)
I/flutter (11127): #121    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1769:7)
I/flutter (11127): #122    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:115:13)
I/flutter (11127): #123    _RenderCustomClip.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:1269:11)
I/flutter (11127): #124    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1769:7)
I/flutter (11127): #125    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:115:13)
I/flutter (11127): #126    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1769:7)
I/flutter (11127): #127    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:115:13)
I/flutter (11127): #128    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1769:7)
I/flutter (11127): #129    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:115:13)
I/flutter (11127): #130    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1769:7)
I/flutter (11127): #131    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:115:13)
I/flutter (11127): #132    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1769:7)
I/flutter (11127): #133    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:115:13)
I/flutter (11127): #134    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1769:7)
I/flutter (11127): #135    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:115:13)
I/flutter (11127): #136    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1769:7)
I/flutter (11127): #137    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:115:13)
I/flutter (11127): #138    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1769:7)
I/flutter (11127): #139    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:115:13)
I/flutter (11127): #140    RenderOffstage.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:3221:13)
I/flutter (11127): #141    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1769:7)
I/flutter (11127): #142    _RenderTheatre.performLayout (package:flutter/src/widgets/overlay.dart:702:15)
I/flutter (11127): #143    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1769:7)
I/flutter (11127): #144    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:115:13)
I/flutter (11127): #145    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1769:7)
I/flutter (11127): #146    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:115:13)
I/flutter (11127): #147    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1769:7)
I/flutter (11127): #148    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:115:13)
I/flutter (11127): #149    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1769:7)
I/flutter (11127): #150    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:115:13)
I/flutter (11127): #151    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1769:7)
I/flutter (11127): #152    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:115:13)
I/flutter (11127): #153    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1769:7)
I/flutter (11127): #154    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:115:13)
I/flutter (11127): #155    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1769:7)
I/flutter (11127): #156    RenderView.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/view.dart:169:13)
I/flutter (11127): #157    RenderObject._layoutWithoutResize (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7)
I/flutter (11127): #158    PipelineOwner.flushLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:889:18)
I/flutter (11127): #159    RendererBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:404:19)
I/flutter (11127): #160    WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:867:13)
I/flutter (11127): #161    RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:286:5)
I/flutter (11127): #162    SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1115:15)
I/flutter (11127): #163    SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1054:9)
I/flutter (11127): #164    SchedulerBinding.scheduleWarmUpFrame.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:863:7)
I/flutter (11127): (elided 14 frames from class _RawReceivePortImpl, class _Timer, dart:async, and dart:async-patch)
I/flutter (11127): 
I/flutter (11127): Image provider: NetworkImage("p1", scale: 1.0)
I/flutter (11127): Image key: NetworkImage("p1", scale: 1.0)
I/flutter (11127): ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (11127): Another exception was thrown: Invalid argument(s): No host specified in URI file:///p2
I/flutter (11127): Another exception was thrown: Invalid argument(s): No host specified in URI file:///p3
I/flutter (11127): Another exception was thrown: Invalid argument(s): No host specified in URI file:///p4
```

Comment: The error says that you're not passing a valid URL to the image widget. "p1" is what you're passing as image URL

Comment: What is `file:///p1`? Is that expected?

Comment: Claudio Redi I too would really like to know where that file:///p1 came from other than only not being expected it is random weird.
This is the message I get when I click on it:
windows cannot find ‘file:///p1’. Make sure you typed the name
correctly and then try again.

Comment: Thanks, solved...the constructor just needed place switching...

Answer (score 0):

Base from the error that you're, it looks like the Image provider is trying to load "p1" as a NetworkImage. Though from the comments, it's likely that the parameters set in have been incorrectly set. Possibly the `id` has been switched with the `imageUrl`.

```dart
ProductItem(
  loadedProducts[index].id,
  loadedProducts[index].imageUrl,
  loadedProducts[index].name,
);
```